# How to force HTTPS on asp.net MVC VNext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, https, asp.net-core

Does someone know how to force HTTPS in MVC Vnext?

I have read a couple of articles about forcing HTTPS in MVC, but in the new version VNext, alot of things have changed so they are all kinda deprecated so im pretty lost right now

Answer (score 1):

That part hasn't changed much. You can use the same RequireHttpsAttribute